# Restoring SQL backup fails - Access is denied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

**Solved. See my answer (but first see my second edit to the question).**

I'm trying to restore a backup for a database from one computer on another - thereby copying the db, but I get this message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The operating system returned the
>   error '5(Access is denied.)' while attempting
>   'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'c:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server...'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Why is this? I *can* create new databases, so why not restore? Is it because it's from another computer? (I read that that's actually a usual way to copy a db so this *shouldn't* be the problem.)

I don't have much experience with this so don't rule out any obvious explanation.

**EDIT :**

I can 'restore' it using the administrator user account to the *administrator's* instance of SQL Server (I have two - one for the administrator, and one for the regular account.) but can't do it from *either* account to the *regular user's* instance of SQL Server.

**EDIT 2 :**

It seems that there are already existing **files** with the backup's files names (even though I changed the existing **db's** name). I'm working on that now (Trying, still unsuccessfully, to restore to different file names).

Comment: I've had failures like that in the past because of a version mismatch. Make sure your restore script and database are of the same version, if not, then check the compatibility options.

Comment: @MrJack Thanks. But I just had the idea to try it from an administrator account and it can be done, but not to the regular user's instance of SQL Server. (See edit in the question.)

Comment: I cannot help much with reg. user accounts though, my use of SQL Server is internal and I'm always admin.

Comment: Windows or sql authentication? Same authentication type for both admin and regular user?

Comment: @larsis Same. Windows.

Comment: Sorry, misread the error msg. Authentication type should not matter. You can specify file name in "restore as" under options when restoring using the ssms gui. Check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx - step 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to make sure that the database was created in the **MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER** folder (as opposed to the **MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS** folder). Then SSMS succeeded in 'restoring' the database.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014, for me path is MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ but still i am getting same error

Answer (score 6):

I just got this error with SQLSERVER14 .All I did is just checking the "**Relocate all files to folder**" checkbox in files tab of the restoration wizard.

The database got restored successfully.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, this actually did the trick in my case! I didn't edit no permission or anything, this did it - thanks again!

Comment: Thank you, this help me.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the similar problem. windows security is preventing to Restore the DB to 'Target' location. Fixing security settings can resolve this issue.

Right click on the Target folder-> Properties -> Security -> Select appropriate user and then Edit the permissions ( I have given Full Access to the user). Hope this would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error message my .bak file was located on my desktop (e.g."C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\database.bak").

When I moved the .bak file to my C drive instead the restore succeeded.